# fgetc and fputc in C

Tags: c, fgetc

I am trying to copy 5 bytes from the start of one file and put them into the start of another file. However they are not copying across accurately. I think the problem is in fputc and fgetc, but not sure what...

```
bmpFile = fopen("frog.bmp", "rb");
encodedFile = fopen("encodedFrog.bmp", "rwb");

for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
    fputc(fgetc(bmpFile), encodedFile); //copy that byte, unchanged into the   output
}

//close and open both files, read the first 5bytes back;
fclose(bmpFile);
fclose(encodedFile);
bmpFile = fopen("frog.bmp", "rb");
encodedFile = fopen("encodedFrog.bmp", "rwb");
for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
    unsigned int actual = fgetc(bmpFile);
    unsigned int value = fgetc(encodedFile);
    printf("actual: %d \tvalue: %d\n", actual, value);
}
```

The result of this is:

```
actual: 66  value: 66
actual: 77  value: 77
actual: 54  value: 134
actual: 115     value: 68
actual: 20  value: 17
```

Thanks

Comment: **[rewind](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/rewind/)**

Comment: For binary read/write, you should really look at `fread` and `fwrite`. You may find them more suited for the task.

Comment: @David: Not necessary or useful. fread and fwrite are identical to repeated calls to fgetc and fputc, respectively.

Comment: Did I say there were different - No, I said you may find them more *useful* and that they provided better *error checking* and *validation*. (see answer below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"rwb"` is not a valid `fopen` mode. You probably want to use

```
fopen("encodedFrog.bmp", "r+b");
```

which will open an existing file for input and output in binary mode. If the file does not exist, you should use `"w+b"`.

```
fopen("encodedFrog.bmp", "w+b");
```

This opens a new file for input and output in binary mode.

Also, as @amdixon mentioned, instead of reopening the files, you should use `rewind`, which resets the stream position to the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

After fixing the `fopen` issue, you may want to look at `fread` and `fwrite` which can provide a bit of additional error checking on binary read/writes.

While there is nothing wrong with reading/writing a character at a time in binary, for file stream input/output in binary you have additional functions `fread` and `fwrite` that allow you to read and write a specific number of bytes (or any other `size` values, e.g. `int`, etc..). The basic syntax is:

```
size_t fread (void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);

size_t fwrite (const void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb,
                FILE *stream);
```

So instead of:

```
for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
    fputc(fgetc(bmpFile), encodedFile);
}
```

You could use `fread` and `fwrite` that allow you to validate the number of elements of `'size'` read and written:

```
unsigned char buf[5] = {0};

if (fread (buf, 1, 5, bmpFile) == 5) {
    if (fwrite (buf, 1, 5, encodedFile) != 5)
        fprintf (stderr, "error: fwrite failed for encodedFile.\n");
}
else
    fprintf (stderr, "error: fread failed for bmpFile.\n");
```

A simple example might be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    FILE *in, *out;
    unsigned char buf[8] = {0};
    unsigned char chr[8] = {0};
    size_t i;

    if (argc < 3) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient input.  prog infile outfile (binary cp)\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (!(in = fopen (argv[1], "r+b")) || !(out = fopen (argv[2], "w+b"))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (fread (buf, 1, 5, in) == 5) {
        if (fwrite (buf, 1, 5, out) != 5)
            fprintf (stderr, "error: fwrite failed for encodedFile.\n");
    }
    else
        fprintf (stderr, "error: fread failed for bmpFile.\n");

    rewind (in);
    rewind (out);

    if (fread (buf, 1, 5, in) != 5 || fread (chr, 1, 5, out) != 5) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: read after rewind failed.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    fclose (in);
    fclose (out);

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        printf (" actual : %3hhu   value : %3hhu\n", buf[i], chr[i]);
    putchar ('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

**Example/Output**

```
$ ./bin/freadfwrite bin/xpathfname bin/ytestout
 actual : 127   value : 127
 actual :  69   value :  69
 actual :  76   value :  76
 actual :  70   value :  70
 actual :   2   value :   2
```